# Webview2 is not loading websites

Tags: webview2

We have a WPF application where we use webview2 in order to load a website and it was working fine till last week.Suddenly it has stopped working and it is not loading any website. Any idea if there is an issue with Webview2 . Anyone else facing similar issue ? As part of investigation I tried to create a sample WPF application following below link and I see the same issue there as well .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

Comment: Have you upgraded the `WebView2` control or runtime when this happened?

Comment: It might also be a bugged Windows update... HAve you found your problem?